# CSS Parent div height is more than child div when child position is relative and its top value is negative. How to contract the height of parent?

Tags: css

Here is the [JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swapnil336/cwbs9gox/20/)

I understand that the extra-height is the height of the child-2 div if it was positioned static.
How can we contract the parent height so that it fits the child divs?

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1">
  </div>
  <div class="child-2">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.child-1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #aaa;
}

.child-2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: -20px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #555;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parent has extended hight because `postion:relative` elements still occupy their original space in normal flow.

In order to contract the parent you've to take it out if normal flow, one way to do this is to apply `position:absolute` to the child, and then position it relative to the parent by giving it `position:relative`

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.child-1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #aaa;
}

.child-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-1">
  </div>
  <div class="child-2">
  </div>

</div>
```